# pytest parametrized class method execution order

Tags: python, pytest

For example I have a pytest file like this:

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize("param",[1,2])
class TestTest():
    def test_1(self, param):
        pass
    def test_2(self,param):
        pass
```

when I run it as output I get:

```
test_tmp.py::TestTest::test_1[1]
test_tmp.py::TestTest::test_1[2]
test_tmp.py::TestTest::test_2[1]
test_tmp.py::TestTest::test_2[2]
```

It is not the order I expect. Is there a way to run tests in this order:

```
test_tmp.py::TestTest::test_1[1]
test_tmp.py::TestTest::test_2[1]
test_tmp.py::TestTest::test_1[2]
test_tmp.py::TestTest::test_2[2]
```

e.g. run all class methods with the first param and afterward run with the second parameter.

Comment: I do not think it is possible to choose execution order of tests but I know that forcing the execution order for tests is a bad practice. Tests should not be affected by the order they are executed, so it should not be any reason to force their order.

Answer (score 2):

In your case we are speaking about order of applying different parameters to different tests. Pytest run each test with all parameters and after that next test and so on.

If by some reasons you need to run two tests with the same parameter, after that to run them with other parameter and so on, I think that means that in reality this is just one complex test with parameters, you should not write it as two separate pytest tests.

In general you can use [pytest-ordering](https://pytest-ordering.readthedocs.io/en/develop/) to order tests themselves.
Or implement the same functionality by yourself in pytest hook

```
pytest_collection_modifyitems(session, config, items)
```

(rearrange items).

But this is bad practice to expect that tests would run in some particular order.
They should be stateless and independant.
After all may be in future you would need parallel test execution or using some subset of your tests.
In any case if tests depend on execution order then they are hard to maintain.

If you need just some ordered results use reporting tools ([yandex allure](http://allure.qatools.ru) for example).

Answer (score -2):

You don't need to write classes in `py.test`:

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize("param",[1,2])
def test_1(param):
    pass

@pytest.mark.parametrize("param",[1,2])
def test_2(param):
    pass
```

will run the tests in the wanted order.

Comment: did you try your code? it runs the first test case twice, and then second TC 2 times

Comment: exactly. This is the purpose of parametrize. Please check the original code also.